# How to do a Full Outer Join using old style Oracle syntax

Tags: oracle, join, oracle8

I have two tables with the same columns, Item Code and Qty, for each Table:

```
TABLE A                    TABLE B
--------------             -------------
X    2                      X   1
Y    1                      S   2
Z    5                      Z   5
```

The result that I am aiming to get is something like this:

```
Table C
---------------
X  2  1
Y  1  0
S  0  2
```

I only need the items where  `qty` differs in both tables (including the nulls which should be shown as zeroes.

Note: I am using Oracle8 so I can't use the ANSI FULL OUTER JOIN.

Comment: What version of oracle?

Comment: Oracle8? Really? That has been put out of support for ages. You should really, really think about an upgrade.

Comment: Why The Negative Vote ???!

Comment: Probably because you didn't say which version of Oracle you were using, something that is *highly pertinent* to the answer. Three people wasted their time providing answers which you couldn't use because you failed to provide that simple piece of information.

Comment: @nayef Out of interest, why are you still on Oracle 8? I hated that whole major release.

Comment: @DavidAldridge the retail Company I Work Didn't Approve The Budget to upgrade this Year Hopefully Next Year :) Its Giving Me A Head Ache also

Comment: Presumably they haven't approved the budget for the last decade.

Comment: This question has been the best fun ever.

Comment: (late to the party) For future reference: http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down *"Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect."*

Comment: (I admit I haven't always adhered to that guideline consistently in the past)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Edit, Since the question is specific to Oracle 8 which does not use ANSI syntax, the following should work:

```
select col1, 
  nvl(a_col2, 0) as a_col2, 
  nvl(b_col2, 0) as b_col2
from 
( 
  select a.col1, a.col2 as a_col2, b.col2 as b_col2 
  from TableA a, TableB b
  where a.col1 = b.col1(+)
  union
  select b.col1, a.col2 as a_col2, b.col2 as b_col2 
  from TableA a, TableB b
  where a.col1(+) = b.col1 
)      
where a_col2 <> b_col2
  or (a_col2 is null or b_col2 is null)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/34cb0/25). This will return:

```
| COL1 | A_COL2 | B_COL2 |
--------------------------
|    S |      0 |      2 |
|    X |      2 |      1 |
|    Y |      1 |      0 |
```

If you are using a version of Oracle that supports ANSI syntax then you can use the following `FULL OUTER JOIN`:

```
select 
  coalesce(a.col1, b.col1) col1, 
  coalesce(a.col2, 0) a_col2, 
  coalesce(b.col2, 0) b_col2
from tablea a
full outer join tableb b
  on a.col1 = b.col1
where a.col2 <> b.col2
  or (a.col2 is null or b.col2 is null);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/34cb0/20)

Comment: It Wont Except Full Outer Join as Syntax i can use the (+) sign

Comment: @nayefharb What version of oracle are you using?

Comment: This is the clearest benefit of the newer ANSI joins;  we can't do this half as easily in pre-9i Oracle using the `(+)` syntax.

Comment: @DavidAldridge They had not stated Oracle 8 until after this answer was posted. I have added a note, but I think the downvote is completely unfair

Comment: @APC remember that answers here are not useful only for the OP. Future readers may benefit from answers especially since most people trying to solve this problem won't still be running Oracle 8. In fact the OP may get the most use out of this answer after all, if and when they migrate from that archaic platform.

Comment: @nayefharb See my edit I added a version that should work in Oracle 8

Comment: @APC dude, go step outside and look at the sky for a few minutes. Nobody stole your solution. Accusing someone of theft is a pretty serious allegation, and I'd be very careful about spraying that kind of crap around.

Comment: @APC If you notice my version is not the same.  Your version actually does not work, I tested it in SQL Fiddle and it only returned one row.

Comment: My solution worked in my test environment but I guess something got lost in the retyping.  Anyway I have deleted my answer and I aplogise for any offence caused by my comments.

Comment: @aaronb - regarding answers which don't help the OP but may be relevant to future szeekers: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166566/lots-of-not-always-useful-but-well-intentioned-answers

Comment: @APC don't see how that's related to this specific scenario, and I hardly see any community consensus there in any case. Do you see any specific policy anywhere that states that SO users must down-vote answers that are later found to not help the OP because they forgot to mention which version they were using? Or that an answer should be down-voted because it is a useful answer for most but doesn't directly satisfy the OP due to some variable (e.g. they are running an unsupported version)? You are of course free to down-vote whatever you like for any reason. But lighten up.

Answer (score 4):

Another writing of the query which should work in 8 and (probably earlier versions).

It uses neither `FULL JOIN` not the horrible `(+)` syntax for joins so it should work even when an upgrade deprecates it.

Assuming that there are no Nulls already on the tables, you won't need `COALESCE()` or `NVL()` either:

```
SELECT  a.col1, 
        a.col2 AS a_col2, 
        b.col2 AS b_col2
FROM    TableA a, TableB b
WHERE   a.col1 = b.col1
  AND ( a.col2 <> b.col2
     OR a.col2 IS NULL
     OR b.col2 IS NULL
      )

UNION ALL

SELECT  col1, col2, 0
FROM    TableA a
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        ( SELECT  *
          FROM    TableB b
          WHERE   a.col1 = b.col1
        )

UNION ALL

SELECT  col1, 0, col2
FROM    TableB b
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        ( SELECT  *
          FROM    TableA a 
          WHERE   a.col1 = b.col1
        ) ;
```

Tests at **[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/34cb0/28)**

Answer (score 2):

```
select code, nvl(a.qty,0) a, nvl(b.qty,0) b
from tableA a full join tableB b using(code)
where decode(a.qty, b.qty, 0) is null
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b2fcc/4)

Comment: Hey @David would you stop down-voting everyone who answered before the OP bothered to mention what version he was using? A comment would suffice instead of punishing them for assuming the user wasn't on a 15-year-old platform.

Comment: Well I didn't conduct a forensic analysis of the exact timings of everything before voting, and unfortunately I can't un-downvote 'em ... apparently it gets locked in by stackoverflow unless the answer is edited. Sheesh! Anyway, if you want to make some minor edit to satisfy stackoverflow I'll take the downvote off ...

Comment: @AaronBertrand Sorry For the Version Trouble i didn't Know that it was a version issue i am a SQL server  guy

Comment: @DavidAldridge your responses here have been very gracious indeed in my opinion, 'reasonable' really is your middle name! It's also great to see you on dba.se and I do hope we see more of you over there :)

Comment: @AaronBertrand - regardless of when the OP posted their version, the fact remains that ANSI syntax solutions are not an appropriate answer to this thread, and hence downvoting is justified.

Comment: @APC I guess we'll have to agree to disagree. *shrug*

Comment: @nayef I don't think you could have known that it would cause this much strife (I think comments would have been more than sufficient once the version was revealed). However you should *always* include the version when posting questions - you can't always know in advance when the version is actually quite relevant.

Answer (score 2):

Another option:

```
select
  full_list.item_code,
  nvl(table_a.qty,0) table_a_qty,
  nvl(table_b.qty,0) table_b_qty
from
  (select item_code from table_a
   union
   select item_code from table_b) full_list,
  table_a,
  table_b
where
  full_list.item_code = table_a.item_code(+) and
  full_list.item_code = table_b.item_code(+)
```

Comment: Not sure, possibly retribution for down-voting everyone else, who answered before they knew the system was from the dark ages.

Comment: SQL fiddle don't do 8i, so it's relevance would be a bit suspect. Anyway, fat distracted finger error corrected in the answer

Comment: @DavidAldridge SQL Fiddle should be able to support the older syntax, I have no experience with Oracle 8, but this fiddle seems to be working and with a few alterations it returns the result the OP wanted -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cc96f/9

Answer (score 0):

The following query should work just right:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT nvl(a.c1, b.c2), nvl(a.col1, 0) qty1, nvl(b.col2, 0) qty2 FROM a FULL OUTER JOIN b ON a.c1 = b.c2
) where qty1 != qty2;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d37ff/5/0